# How to handle bit fields in Wireshark Lua dissector?

Tags: lua, wireshark, wireshark-dissector

I need to dissect a bit mapped octet in a Wireshark lua dissector. The octet has format:

```
bit 0:     Concatenation (0=No concatenation, 1=Concatenation)
bits 1..3: Reserved
bits 4..7: Version
```

I have successfully dissected it with:

```
Concatenation_F = ProtoField.uint8("Concatenation", "Concatenation", base.DEC, NULL, 0x1)
Version_F = ProtoField.uint8("Version", "Version", base.DEC, NULL, 0xF0)

my_protocol.fields = { Concatenation_F,
                   Version_F
}

<snip>

local Concatenation_range = buffer(0,1)
local Version_range = buffer(0,1)

local Concatenation = Concatenation_F:uint()
local Version = Version_range:uint()

subtree:add(Concatenation_F, Concatenation_range, Concatenation)
subtree:add(Version_F, Version_range, Version)
```

That works, but I would like to show the meaning of the Concatenation field, like:

[image]

but to do that I need to get the value of the Concatenation bit. How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 solutions.  Normally you'd just introduce a valuestring and use it in your `ProtoField` call.  For example:

```
local yesno_types = {
    [0] = "No",
    [1] = "Yes"
}

Concatenation_F = ProtoField.uint8("Concatenation", "Concatenation", base.DEC, yesno_types, 0x1)
```

Refer to section **11.6.7. ProtoField** of the [Wireshark Developer's Guide](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/lua_module_Proto.html) for more information.

But if you still want to get the value of the bitfield, then you can do so using [Lua BitOp](http://lua-users.org/wiki/BitwiseOperators) support, which is already available to you.  So, something like this:

```
local function get_concat(x) return bit.band(x, 0x01) end

local concat = get_concat(buffer(0, 1):uint())
```